# Replacing Values in SQL (Microsoft Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

So: I have a small table which looks like :

```
PartNumber  ReplacedNumber
408077-5102 408077-5102S
408077-0102 408077-5102
```

As you can see here, i want to replace the Part number with a Replaced number, with the issue being if a is replaced by b, and b replaced by c, then it implies that a is replaced by c.

Anyone knowing a way to do this?

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE:**
Okay, here is the sample data:

```
id PartNumber   ReplacedNumber
1  408077-5102  408077-5102S
2  408077-0102  408077-5102
```

As you can see, the value in the 2nd row is replaced (a is replaced by b, which in this case `408077-0102` is replaced by `408077-5102`), and then b is replaced by c (`408077-5102` is replaced by `408077-5102S` in the 1st row).

That implies a = c. I want to avoid replacing values in repetition. I hope it is clearer now.

Thanks

Comment: please post your question even more descriptive.tel your desired output clearly.

Comment: What is a,b and c and which column it is located? Can you provide sample data and your desired result set?

Comment: Okay, here is the sample data: id PartNumber ReplacedNumber
                                1  408077-5102 408077-5102S
                                2  408077-0102 408077-5102
As you can see, the value in the 2nd row is replaced ( a is replaced by b, which in this case 408077-0102 is replaced by 408077-5102 ), and then b is replaced by c. (408077-5102 is replaced by 408077-5102S in the 1st row.  That implies a = c.  I want to avoid replacing values in repetition.  I hope it is clearer now.
Thanks

Comment: you just tell what is the output you need

Comment: I guess it could be done in several ways.  2 rows will result in 1, so what I need is to merge the 2 rows into 1. I hope you understood the problem.

Comment: @KristiaProkopiou How do you decide which value is replaced by which? How 408077-5102 is converted into 408077-5102S and how 408077-0102 is converted into 408077-5102? What is the criteria? Paste your table structure also please

Comment: Okay, so the data is fixed. its given, the numbers are not automatically replaced by another number.
What I want to achieve is just the checking of the number that was replaced not to be replaced twice.  
Step 1: 40877-0102 is replaced by 408077-5102 as shown on the table.
Step 2: 40877-5102 is replaced AGAIN by 40877-5012S.
Conclusion: I want to avoid this.  So how to I delete the unecessary row so the repetition is not shown in the resulting table?
I hope this time I'm clear.
Thanks

Comment: @KristiaProkopiou It's still not clear enough, you need to address **Ertunc's** question, referring to A,B,C in this instance means nothing, what is your logic behind how the numbers are replaced and what they are replaced with?

Comment: Please see the update for a,b and c.  The numbers replaced are given.  What I want to do is avoid replacing twice.  That necessarily means that it will result to 1 row, instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

If a is replaced by b, and b is replaced by c, then it implies that a is replaced by c could be written as this:

```
SELECT
  Replace.ID,
  Replace.PartNumber,
  IIF(Not IsNull([Replace_1].[ReplacedNumber]),
      [Replace_1].[ReplacedNumber],
      [Replace].[ReplacedNumber])
FROM
  Replace LEFT JOIN Replace AS Replace_1
    ON Replace.ReplacedNumber = Replace_1.PartNumber
```

(it's a SELECT query but it could be easily transformed in a UPDATE query) but this does not solve the case of c replaced by d, that (i suppose) also implies that a is replaced by d.

I think the only solution here is to use a recursive function:

```
Function searchReplaced(ReplacedNumber) as Variant
  Dim Look As Variant

  Look = DLookup("ReplacedNumber",
                 "Replace",
                 "PartNumber=""" & ReplacedNumber & """")

  If IsNull(Look) Then
    searchReplaced = ReplacedNumber
  Else
    searchReplaced = searchReplaced(Look)
  End If

End Function
```

And then you just launch this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE Replace
SET Replace.ReplacedNumber = searchReplace([Replace].[ReplacedNumber])
```

Comment: That looks like it could work.  Thanks a lot, I will try both and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If that table has primary id, you can just update the table

```
update table set partnumber=replacednumber where id=id of the column you want to replace
```

id refers to primary key

Comment: Okay, here is the sample data: id PartNumber ReplacedNumber
                                1  408077-5102 408077-5102S
                                2  408077-0102 408077-5102
As you can see, the value in the 2nd row is replaced ( a is replaced by b, which in this case 408077-0102 is replaced by 408077-5102 ), and then b is replaced by c. (408077-5102 is replaced by 408077-5102S in the 1st row.  That implies a = c.  I want to avoid replacing values in repetition.  I hope it is clearer now.
Thanks

Comment: @KristiaProkopiou: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: I apologise.  I'm new, I just signed up so give me some time to learn how to use the site. Thanks for your patience